# mp4 video doesn't play on mobile, but it plays locally

Tags: ffmpeg

I built a mp4 video from jpg images using this command:

`ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i img%d.jpg -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 1 output.mp4`

I can open and play video on my computer (in VLC and in a browser), but I can't play it on mobile (Chrome 116.0.5845.93 on Android 11, the phone is Oppo A73). There's info about duration, I can press the "play" button, but the video doesn't play at all.

It has 1920 × 1280 resolution and 16 seconds length - as expected.

```
$ ffprobe output.mp4             
ffprobe version 6.0 Copyright (c) 2007-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/6.0 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
  Duration: 00:00:16.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1173 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/unknown/unknown, progressive), 1920x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 1172 kb/s, 1 fps, 1 tbr, 16384 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 libx264
```

How to fix that?

Comment: Well what dimensions are the video? You've give us nothing to work with here. `ffprobe output.mp4` would help, along with what your phone is!

Comment: @KenSharp I updated the description

Comment: Try adding `-profile main`